# Writing a program to stop another program from taking screenshots

Tags: c#, screenshot

So I was wondering if there is a way to prevent a program from taking screenshots or allowing a program to take screenshots but blackened to image.

**Program that takes screen shot is as follows:**

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace ScreenCapture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

        private void PrintScreen()
        {

            Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

            printscreen.Save(@"C:\Temp\printscreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

*If I handle PrintScr returning null would it work?*

*P.S. : Its not like I want to prevent a program from having its screenshot taken, I want to prevent program from taking screen shots of the complete desktop screen*

Basically, I have a program that is taking screenshots every min,i.e., monitor the user's activity. I want a create a program to nullify it. **NOT STOP THE PROGRAM**

Comment: `Process.GetProcessByName("ScreenCapture.exe").First().Kill()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072329/how-to-intercept-each-trying-to-use-api-function-in-c

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554018/how-to-prevent-screenshot-from-program

Comment: @dcastro I dont want to kill the program.

Comment: You could try setting the TransparentKey property of the form you want to hide to anything other than `null`.  There are probably ways around this and it's probably a side effect rather than designed, but it's worth a try and works for the simple screen capture example you shown above.  Otherwise, se if the UIPermission class can offer anything.

Comment: You could also look into [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd375340(v=vs.85).aspx).  I think you'd need to pinvoke it from c#, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: There's also a bunch of [anti key logging](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/what-is-the-best-anti-keylogger-and-anti-screen-capture-software/) software that will do it.

Comment: @MikeofSST Many thanks.... SetWindowDisplayAffinity is exactly what I was looking for....But it works for the program in which I have code it how would I apply it on the whole desktop screen?

Comment: I don't know if you can - I expect you'll get a permission exception if you try to set it on the desktop.  I've only ever used it on my own applications.

Comment: @MikeofSST I see,.....d(^ ^)

Comment: @MikeofSST Just a thought,....What if I create a transparent form that runs foreground always but does register input....kinda like AVS Screen Capture?